# parse.com How to use query limit with query each?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I need to order and limit my query, then I need to iterate on the result but is not possible.

```
Cannot iterate on a query with sort, skip, or limit.
```

How can I make ?

This is my query, I want my publish post, with tags user and limit to 100 last post:

```
var query = new Parse.Query('post');
    query.equalTo('publish', true);
    query.descending('createdAt');
    query.containedIn('tags', request.user.get('tags'));
    query.limit(100);
    query.each(function(post) {

        var postJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(post));
        var promises = [];

        var promise1 = getPseudo(post.get('author').id).then(function(user) {
                postJSON.pseudo = user.get('pseudo');
            }, function(error) {});

        var promise2 = isCertified(post.get('author').id).then(function(result) {
                postJSON.isCertified = !!result;
            }, function(error) {});

        promises.push(promise1, promise2);
        promisesAll.push(promise1, promise2);

        Parse.Promise.when(promises)
            .then(function() {
                posts.push(postJSON);
            }, function(error) {});

    }, {
        success: function() {
            Parse.Promise.when(promisesAll)
                .then(function() {
                    response.success(postsOrdered);
                });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you post the query?

Comment: Do not use `each`. Just use `find` and iterate over the array of results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load underscore, like so:
`var _ = require('underscore');`

After you can loop each result like so:

```
var query = new Parse.Query('post');
    query.equalTo('publish', true);
    query.descending('createdAt');
    query.containedIn('tags', request.user.get('tags'));
    query.limit(100);
    query.find({
        success: function(posts) {

            _.each(function(post) {
                // What you want
            }

        }
    });
```